# Instantiate generic type from variable

Tags: c#, variables, object, generics, instantiation

I would like to instantiate a new object where the type and generic type are defined as variables. The final result could look like the newListOfObjects created manually here:

```
var newListOfObjects = new List<TabViewModel>();
```

Where TabViewModel is the following object:

```
public class TabViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int TabOrder { get; set; }
}
```

**The problem comes when trying to instantiate the new object using only variables**. We have one generic type variable, genericType, which is an interface and one list of type arguments, listOfTypeArgs. In the example above the generic type would be IList and the arguments would be TabViewModel. It would then look like following (**note, some code is psudo for easier understanding**):

```
Type genericType = IList'1;
Type[] listOfTypeArgs = TabViewModel;
var newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType.MakeGenericType(listOfTypeArgs));
```

It is then obvious that I get the error 'System.MissingMethodException' with the note that I can not instantiate a variable from an interface.

**How can I convert the interface to its represenative so that I can
instantiate the new object?**

**NOTE: I can not change Type genericType = IList'1; nor
    Type[] listOfTypeArgs = TabViewModel;**

Comment: This `Type genericType = IList'1;` and this `Type[] listOfTypeArgs = TabViewModel;` is not a valid C# syntax. Post the actual code !

Comment: The valid code for getting a type of IList and TabViewModel is in this case irrelevant.

Comment: You might read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting again if you choose to ignore user3185569 s request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self descriptive, you need concrete types to create an instance. Instead of `IList` (Which has no implementation and is just a contract), you need to use an implementation of `IList`:

```
Type genericType = typeof(List<>);
Type[] listOfTypeArgs = new[] { typeof(TabViewModel) };
var newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType.MakeGenericType(listOfTypeArgs));
```

**Edit:**

If you don't have a concrete type, you need to get it either using a container or reflecting the current assemblies. Below is a bit of a hack that you need to tweak the way you find useful for your case.

```
Type genericType = typeof(List<>);
Type concreteType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                            .Where(p => genericType.IsAssignableFrom(p)).FirstOrDefault();

Type[] listOfTypeArgs = new[] { typeof(TabViewModel) };
var newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType.MakeGenericType(listOfTypeArgs));
```

Comment: Lovely answear, but sadly I can not change the genericType variable. I get just the interface, and thats my problem

Comment: @ViktorLeandersson Then you need to use reflection to find an implementation of that interface. Check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `List<>` type like so:

```
var genericType = typeof(List<>);
var boundType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TabViewModel));
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(boundType);
```

Comment: Lovely answear, but sadly I can not change the genericType variable. I get just the interface, and thats my problem

Comment: @ViktorLeandersson Then you could create a map which maps all your possible interfaces to concrete implementations, e.g. `IList<>` maps to `List<>`